# Is it possible to get the another tab url form my page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have google or some other sites in my browser tab. In another tab i have my html page. I want to get the url of that google page in my html page.Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about getting information abut the clients browser opend tabs.. this is not allow via any client side script, it is a security threat what are you trying to achieve please elaborate...

Comment: Only if your own code opened that tab.

Comment: I want to implement the Cobrowsing concept.For this i need to get the url of the opened tabs.

Comment: Wow, you should try another language, you'll not be able to do so with the JavaScript runtime of any browser.

Comment: Oh. Can u please tell how to implement my requirement. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

No 
It is not possible to get the URL of other tabs that are opened by the users
Its against privacy and its a security threat
you can only access the URL of the current tab by using
`window.location`
and `window.location.search` to get the query string

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure what you mean by "Cobrowsing concept" but like vignesh said, it is a security threat to have on a webpage. Probably your best bet would be to write an extension.  Here's how: ([Chrome](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html), [Firefox](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)).

**Edit:** Actually, for Firefox this would be a lot easier: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/

Hope this helps!